# Cannot anonymise data at search time in splunk

Tags: splunk

I have a log file (/var/log/test2.log):

```
[2022-03-25 14:30:08] LoggerTest.INFO: JSON Request to MySystem {"shopperEmail":"my.email@gmail.com"}
```

I have $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/**props.conf**:

```
[source::/var/log/test2.log] 
TRANSFORMS-anonymize = shopperEmail_anonymizer
```

I have $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/**transforms.conf**:

```
[shopperEmail_anonymizer] 
REGEX = (.*)shopperEmail\":\"(.*)\" 
FORMAT = $1shopperEmail: XXX 
DEST_KEY = _raw
```

I have $SPLUNK_HOME/etc/system/local/**inputs.conf**:

```
[monitor:///var/log]
disabled = 0
index=index_name
sourcetype=my_source_type
```

But when I do a search, **shopperEmail** is not anonymised. I expect the event to look in splunk like:

```
[2022-03-25 14:30:08] LoggerTest.INFO: JSON Request to MySystem {"shopperEmail":"**"}
```

Could you please advise what is wrong? I have tried a lot of options, but neither worked.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What "lot of options" have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try using SEDCMD, instead.  I've found it to be simpler and more reliable.

In props.conf:

```
[source::/var/log/test2.log]
SEDCMD-anonShopper = s/shopperEmail\":\"(.*)\"/shopperEmail":"XXX"/
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the wrong forwarder type for this